# Use if else statement in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

```
d = data.frame(A=c(1,1),B=c(0,20),C=c(0,10))
d$B[d$B>0] = TRUE
d$C[d$C>0] = TRUE
d$B[d$B==0] = FALSE
d$C[d$C==0] = FALSE
```

Is there a way to do the 4 last operations in one line to simplify things like an if else statement for dataframe.

Comment: You want to do it only for `B` and `C` columns leaving `A` ?

Comment: Yes only for B and C )

Comment: Can the values be negative as well? Or will it be either greater than 0 or 0 ?

Comment: The values can be >0 or 0

Comment: `d[c("B","C")] <- lapply(d[c("B","C")], `>`, 0)`?

Comment: I think this should be a duplicate of some question, couldn't find something close, hence answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compare the entire dataframe (except the first column) and check if the value is greater than 0 or not and convert that value into numeric

```
d[-1] <- as.numeric(d[-1] > 0)

d
#  A B C
#1 1 0 0
#2 1 1 1
```

Or if we want to keep the values as logical we can remove the `as.numeric` call

```
d[-1] <- d[-1] > 0

#  A     B     C
#1 1 FALSE FALSE
#2 1  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, funs(. > 0))
#  A     B     C
#1 1 FALSE FALSE
#2 1  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use dplyr's if_else as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

d = data.frame(A=c(1,1),B=c(0,20),C=c(0,10))

 d$B<-if_else(d$B>0,"TRUE","FALSE")
 d$C<-if_else(d$C>0,"TRUE","FALSE")


  A     B     C
1 1 FALSE FALSE
2 1  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: If B>0 return "TRUE", if not "FALSE"

Comment: my point is: your ifelse call returns exactly the same as `d$B>0` or actually the same as `as.character(d$B>0)`, which is another part I don't find logical

Comment: `class("TRUE")` vs `class(TRUE)`